# box2d spring mesh with texture map

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, box2d, game-physics

I have an image of a lamp and I'd like to make the base elastic. If a user puts their finger on the base and pulls back, it stretches to a given range. When they let go it snaps back with a certain amount of elasticity.

This youtube video of box2d + springs + texture mapping seems very close to what I want:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cT6ZM3KkqY

I'm new to box2d ( iOS ) and was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video you posted uses soft body dynamics.

The idea is that you create a soft body object made up of a matrix of points like this:

```
0  0  0  0

0  0  0  0

0  0  0  0
```

To render the image, each point of the matrix will be a vertex. Calculating the indices is a trivial task.

Here is a good tutorial for soft body dynamics on iOS using Box2d: http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2012/03/soft-body-physics-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-part-14/